# Should there be a QFT evolution equation which has different orders of time and space derivatives?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, schroedinger-equation

I have seen many QFT equations like Klein-Gordon, Dirac, Weyl, Proca etc.
But they order of the time derivative is always the same as the order of the space derivative.
Shouldn't there be an equation which has this kind of form?

$$i\hbar\partial_t\psi(x,t)=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\partial^2_x\psi(x,t)+mc^2\psi(x,t)$$

Please bear in mind that I am just a beginner.

Comment: To be clear, you've taken the non-relativistic Schrödinger equation and added an $E=mc^2$ term to the Hamiltonian

Comment: What do you mean *"shouldn't there be"*? *Why* should there be such an equation?

Comment: @ACuriousMind he wants to add rest mass to the Hamiltonian in the Schrödinger equation to make it relativistic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The energy in special relativity is 
$$E^2=m^2+p^2$$
That is not equivalent to the classical kinetic energy plus rest-mass energy,
$$E = p^2/2m + m$$
which is an approximation valid if $v\ll c$.

Thus the correct generalisation of the Schrödinger equation is the Klein-Gordon equation
$$ (E^2 -p^2) \phi = m^2 \phi$$
and not your
$$ E \phi = (p^2/2m + m)\phi$$
Note well that the KG equation is second order in time. Attempts to produce a first order Lorentz invariant equation lead eventually to the Dirac equation.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the fact that these are [Lorenz covariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_covariance) equations by construction, and time and space have to be treated  symmetrically. One is  writing the equations in the four dimensional space of special relativity .

Comment: The Hamiltonian isn't Lorentz covariant or imvariant though, as it transforms like an energy...

Comment: From $H= \dot\phi dL/d\dot\phi -L$ I think the Hamiltonian could easily have powers of spatial derivatives other than one, even for LI Lagrangians